# MySQL Couting Distinct values when grouping by dates

Tags: mysql

I do have two tables, one is a calendar table with a DATE column, and the other contains ID's and three DATES for each ID.

Calendar Table:

```
dt
2016-01-01
2016-01-02
2016-01-03
2016-01-04
...
```

Data Table:

```
ID          d_created          d_forwarded          d_solved
1           2016-01-01         2016-01-02           2016-01-03
2           2016-01-01         2016-01-02           2016-01-03
3           2016-01-02         2016-01-02           2016-01-04
4           2016-01-03         2016-01-04           2016-01-05
...
```

The Data Table does in reality contain a multitude of other fields, but I think that is irrelevant for my question. I have a query which selects the DATE field from the calendar table for a given range, let's say a month, and then I do a LEFT JOIN with the Data Table using all three DATE fields combined with OR, because I need to count multiple things from the Data Table, some depending on the d_created, some depending on the d_forwarded and others on d_solved:

```
SELECT 

tc.dt AS dt,

COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE 
WHEN td.id != 0
AND DATE(td.d_solved) >= '2016-01-01'
AND DATE(td.d_solved) <= '2016-01-31'
THEN td.id
ELSE NULL
END)) AS result1

.... more stmts ...

FROM calendar_table tc
LEFT JOIN data_table td ON tc.dt = DATE(td.d_created) OR tc.dt = DATE(td.d_solved) OR tc.dt = DATE(td.d_forwarded)
```

Now here's my problem: The query delivers the correct output, when I do not group my results by tc.dt, but as soon as I group it by tc.dt, the results are incorrect. I am by no means an SQL expert, but as far as I understand it, td.id will occur more than once due to the JOIN, and as long as I have a single result row, the DISTINCT prevents an ID from being counted twice.

I need to be able to count all ID's which have been created, solved or forwarded within my date range, and I also need the calendar table join because I would like to display each day in the range, even though there might be no matching dates in my data table for a particular day, if that makes sense.

Is there any way I can make sure that no ID is counted more than one time when grouping by days ?

I hope I could make clear what the exact problem is, if not, please let me know and I try to elaborate in more detail.

**UPDATE**
I tried using SarathChandra example which looks quite promising and it does indeed deliver results, however as soon as I add more criteria to my CASE WHEN statement, it does not work the way it should. I forked and modified SarathChandra's ideaone fiddle [HERE](http://ideone.com/6Pzx1H)

So it should return 1 for the 2016-01-02 date but it shows a 0 ?

**UPDATE 2**
Unfortunately, none of the provided answers was able to solve the underlying problem. While both suggestions were appreciated a lot, I ended up splitting the query into three queries, each time joining the calendar table with the same range of dates, and then combining the arrays in PHP to a single result set.

Comment: group by date AND id

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you join on multiple columns, so when you group on date you'll for example get the *ID 1* for the '2016-01-01' (created), '2016-01-02' (solved) and '2016-01-03' (forwarded).

You could try to join to the same table 3 times and count the results in 3 columns. The sum of each column should then match the number of records.

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/343d83/3/0)

Query:

```
SELECT tc.dt AS dt,
       COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN td_solved.id != 0
                      AND DATE(td_solved.d_solved) >= '2016-01-01'
                      AND DATE(td_solved.d_solved) <= '2016-01-31' THEN td_solved.id ELSE NULL END)) AS solved,
       COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN td_created.id != 0
                      AND DATE(td_created.d_created) >= '2016-01-01'
                      AND DATE(td_created.d_created) <= '2016-01-31' THEN td_created.id ELSE NULL END)) AS created,
       COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN td_forwarded.id != 0
                      AND DATE(td_forwarded.d_forwarded) >= '2016-01-01'
                      AND DATE(td_forwarded.d_forwarded) <= '2016-01-31' THEN td_forwarded.id ELSE NULL END)) AS forwarded
FROM calendar_table tc
LEFT JOIN data_table td_created ON tc.dt = DATE(td_created.d_created)
LEFT JOIN data_table td_solved ON tc.dt = DATE(td_solved.d_solved)
LEFT JOIN data_table td_forwarded ON tc.dt = DATE(td_forwarded.d_forwarded)
GROUP BY 1 WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: In my first attempts to solve this problem, I tried joining the table three times because having three separate aliases for each join date would indeed solve the problem, unfortunately the execution time will exceed the server timeout when doing that. Any idea why ? The table has roughly 16000 rows and all my date fields are indexed, while ID is the primary key.

Comment: If the time-stamps in `d_created`, `d_solved` and `d_forwarded` are really dates you can remove the `DATE()` function when joining.
If you apply `DATE()` to the indexed columns mysql can't use the index since it first has to calculate the date for each row. (I updated the Fiddle so you can see the execution plan)

Comment: I did not know that, this information will come in handy in the future indeed. But even when the EXPLAIN showed that I had a key and an index for each result set the query took way too long to execute. It is used to create a report on the fly, so a 5 Minute query was not an option. Cheers for your effort mate.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some assumptions regarding the data in arriving at the following solution:

1. `d_created` shall precede `d_forwarded`, which in turn shall precede `d_solved`.
2. In order to remove duplicate counts, that is, count each record only once, I am joining on the basis of the least of the three dates.

The below query seems to be working fine for me.

```
SELECT 
tc.dt AS dt,
COUNT(
  CASE WHEN DATE(td.d_created) BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-31' THEN td.id 
  ELSE NULL END) AS `Count`
FROM calendar_table tc
LEFT JOIN data_table td ON 
(tc.dt = LEAST(DATE(td.d_created), DATE(td.d_solved), DATE(td.d_forwarded)))
GROUP BY tc.dt;
```

UPDATE: Working example code [here](http://ideone.com/NMdvrn).

Comment: An interesting approach, I really like the LEAST option in the join criteria, unfortunately both the d_forwarded and d_solved can be '0000-00-00' indicating it was never forwarded nor solved. I tried expanding your join arguments by adding "AND d_forwarded > '0000-00-00' AND d_solved > '0000-00-00' but the query only returns 0 results.

Comment: The query seems to be working for me even for '0000-00-00' or null values for d_solved / d_forwarded dates. Unfortunately the SQLFiddle link is not working.

Comment: Yeah I tried creating a fiddle to replicate my current data structure, but the fiddle site kept crashing all the time : ( .. I will double check that I implemented your suggestion in the correct manner and try again though.

Comment: Okay I must have messed something up in the first attempt, your query does indeed deliver results, but as soon as I add another criteria to the CASE WHEN it does show only 0 again. I have a VARCHAR column called "classification" in my data_table and I added a "AND classification LIKE '%BLAH%' to the CASE WHEN, as soon as I remove that I get results. Any idea why that is ? I whish I could demonstrate in the fiddle.